# ImportError: cannot import name 'pluggable' from 'google.auth' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/__init__.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Even though I did

`pip3 install google-auth` that doesn't resolve the error, any idea?

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gslib/utils/wrapped_credentials.py", line 33, in <module>
    from google.auth import pluggable
ImportError: cannot import name 'pluggable' from 'google.auth' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/__init__.py)
```

[image]

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]